# Row wise calculation and addition of new column based on the result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a event log table which captures the status of the event from creation to assignment with Id as a unique identifier. I want to calculate  the duration of between the event is created and when it is assigned, also if for an Id the event is created but not assigned then it should add a value to a new column.

Input table:

| timestamp | event | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03 10:00am | created | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 10:01am | processing | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 10:04am | assigned | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 10:03am | created | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 10:04am | processing | 2 |

Desired output:

| ID | to assigned duration | not assigned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 sec | 0 |
| 2 | null | 1 |

I tried adding a new column assigned while checking if event contains the  value assigned then 1 else 0, but that did not work.

Comment: Results are not going to be seconds when you are showing a difference of minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Get time difference for consecutive rows](//stackoverflow.com/q/27721384/90527)", "[Compute for duration of every occurence of a record](//stackoverflow.com/q/49147282/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by id` and use `datediff`:

```
select id,
    datediff(mi, 
        min(case when event = 'created' then timestamp end), 
        min(case when event = 'assigned' then timestamp end)
    ) as [to assigned duration],
    coalesce(max(case when event = 'assigned' then 0 end), 1) as [not assigned]
from table_name
group by id;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59e9e2a157b2664499623fbff222b170)